# Copy nested table's values in another tuple of same table

Tags: oracle11g, nested

I have the following table in oracle 11g named parlamentari:

> cf varchar(16) 
>   nome varchar(20) 
>   cognome varchar(20) 
>   telefoni telefoni_NT

where telefoni_NT is a nested table of varchar2.
Now, I must to copyed the elements of the nested table of a tuple (sorgente) in another tuple (ricevente).
I try to write an example

Start situation

```
parlamentari
-------------------------------------
cf | nome | cognome | telefoni 
-------------------------------------
 1 |   a  |    aa   |  VARCHAR(222,444)
 2 |   b  |    bb   |  VARCHAR(111)
```

Situation after procedure called

```
parlamentari
-------------------------------------
cf | nome | cognome | telefoni 
-------------------------------------
 1 |   a  |    aa   |  VARCHAR(222,444)
 2 |   b  |    bb   |  VARCHAR(111, 222, 444)
```

I tried to written this procedure without success

```
create or replace procedure copia_telefoni2
(sorgente in parlamento2018.parlamentari.cf%type,
 ricevente in parlamento2018.parlamentari.cf%type) as

cursor cur_out_tel is 
  select column_value as original_list 
  from parlamentari, table(telefoni)
  where cf = sorgente
 ;

cursor in_parlamentare is 
  select column_value as copied_list 
  from parlamentari, table(telefoni)
  where cf = destinazione;

begin

  if (sorgente <> destinazione) then

    for i in cur_out_tel loop
      dbms_output.put_line(i.original_list);

          insert into table(select telefoni from parlamentari where cf=destinazione) values (telefoni_nt(i.original_list));

    end loop;
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Errore! Sorgente e destinazione uguali');
  end if;

end copia_telefoni2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Copy nested table's values in another tuple of same table

As far i could understand your requirement, you don't need to `insert` in the `table` since the record already exists in your table. All you need is to update the existing record. Since your table column is a `nested` table,[MULTISET UNION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/operators006.htm) is something which would work in your situation. See below demo:

Tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE telefoni_nt IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

CREATE TABLE parlamentari (
    cf         VARCHAR(16),
    nome       VARCHAR(20),
    cognome    VARCHAR(20),
    telefoni   telefoni_nt
)
NESTED TABLE telefoni STORE AS nested_telefoni;

insert into parlamentari values('1','a','aa',telefoni_nt('VARCHAR(222,444)'));

insert into parlamentari values('2','b','bb',telefoni_nt('VARCHAR(111)'));
```

Output:

```
SQL> Select CF ,TELEFONI from parlamentari;

        CF           TELEFONI
        --           ------
        1            TELEFONI_NT('VARCHAR(222,444)')
        2            TELEFONI_NT('VARCHAR(111)')
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE copia_telefoni2 (
    sorgente       IN parlamentari.cf%TYPE,
    destinazione   IN parlamentari.cf%TYPE
) AS

BEGIN
    IF ( sorgente <> destinazione )        
    THEN    
            --Using MULTISET Operator to merge the destination column element with the source column elements.
            UPDATE parlamentari
                SET
                    telefoni = telefoni MULTISET UNION (SELECT telefoni 
                                                        FROM parlamentari 
                                                        WHERE cf = sorgente )
            WHERE
                cf = destinazione;
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('Errore! Sorgente e destinazione uguali');
    END IF;
COMMIT;
END copia_telefoni2;
/
```

Execution:

```
SQL> EXEC copia_telefoni2('1','2');

 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> Select CF ,TELEFONI from parlamentari;

            CF           TELEFONI
            --           ------
            1            TELEFONI_NT('VARCHAR(222,444)')
            2            TELEFONI_NT('VARCHAR(111)','VARCHAR(222,444)')
```

So you can see in the result that the two rows now have been merged.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I've another question on this problem. If do i wanted to use the cast operator (I know who this operator is deprecatad)?

Comment: Cast will throw error or inconsistent datatype since you are trying to update a column not a collection.

Comment: But can telefoni be considerated a collection?

Comment: Yes,,its a collection but in this case its just not working. :-)